# Encode MongoDB Object Id to shorter form

Tags: mongodb, encoding

How to encode 12-byte BSON string of MongoDb's ObjectId to shorter form.
From 24 length line to 8 or 6?

I have tried  base64 encoding and for now i'm using plain string value of ObjectID

Requirements

1. Shorter length 4 - 8 symbols
2. Two way encoding

String will be used as unique short url.

`ObjectId -> http://bla.com/{encode(ObjectId.toString('ascii'))} -`

And reverse operation

`http://bla.com/gf8a4as1 -> Model.findById(decode(gf8a4as1)).lean().exec().then((model) =>  res.json(model)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to reversibly pack 12 bytes into 4-8 symbols? That's impossible unless you use characters that are longer than 1 byte (which is probably suboptimal for urls).

You best option is to use a variant of base64 (standard urlsafe variant from RFC4648, for example, with `-` and `_` as), it'll give you exactly 16 symbols. Otherwise, consider using shorter ids (say, sequential numbers?) if you don't require global uniqueness.